# How to put a check on Empty TextField?

Tags: iphone

Str is empty i mean i enter nothing in TextFied even then it's going in else case
    NSString *Str= textField.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",Str);

```
if([Str isEqualToString:@""])
{
   NSLog(@"Hi");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
if ( [string length] <= 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

if(str == NULL)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(!textField.text.length)
```

**or**

```
if([txtField.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The Below code will check for the empty textfield and even for the whitespaces.

NSString *firstNameWithNoSpaces = [firstNameTxtField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    if (![firstNameWithNoSpaces length] <= 0 ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

`if([textfield.text isEqualToString:@""] || textfield.text== nil )`